# How to fix the Key Error when creating plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, keyerror

I am comparing multiple classifiers on my own dataset.
Whilst plotting, I get the Error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py
>   in to_rgba(c, alpha)
>       173     try:
>   --> 174         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
>       175     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
>
> KeyError: ('myLabel', None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py
>   in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha,
>   linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)    4231             try:  #
>   Then is 'c' acceptable as PathCollection facecolors?
>   -> 4232                 colors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c)    4233                 n_elem = colors.shape[0]
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py
>   in to_rgba_array(c, alpha)
>       274     for i, cc in enumerate(c):
>   --> 275         result[i] = to_rgba(cc, alpha)
>       276     return result
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py
>   in to_rgba(c, alpha)
>       175     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
>   --> 176         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
>       177         try:
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py
>   in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
>       219             pass
>   --> 220         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
>       221     # tuple color.
>
> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'myLabel'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        21     # Plot the training points
>        22     ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train.ravel(), cmap=cm_bright,
>   ---> 23                edgecolors='k')
>        24 
>        25
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py
>   in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)    1808
>   "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.**name**),    1809
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   -> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1811     1812         inner.**doc** = _add_data_doc(inner.**doc**,
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py
>   in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha,
>   linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)    4251
>   "or as numbers to be mapped to colors. "    4252
>   "Here c = {}."  # <- beware, could be long depending on c.
>   -> 4253                     .format(c)    4254                 )    4255         else:
>
> ValueError: 'c' argument must either be valid as mpl color(s) or as
>   numbers to be mapped to colors. Here c = ['myLabel' 'myLabel'
>   'myLabel' ... 'myLabel' 'myLabel' 'myLabel'].

Here the code I use (from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html)

```
y = labels
X = features

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

h = .02  # step size in the mesh
names = ["RBF SVM", "Random Forest", "Neural Net",
         "Naive Bayes"]
classifiers = [

    SVC(gamma=2, C=1),

    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=10, max_features=1),
    MLPClassifier(alpha=1),
    GaussianNB()
]

linearly_separable = (X, y)

datasets = [make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0),
            make_circles(noise=0.2, factor=0.5, random_state=1),
            linearly_separable
            ]

figure=plt.figure(figsize=[40,20])

i = 1
# iterate over datasets
for ds_cnt, ds in enumerate(datasets):
    # preprocess dataset, split into training and test part
    X, y = ds
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.4, random_state=42)

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

    # just plot the dataset first
    cm = plt.cm.RdBu
    cm_bright = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#0000FF'])
    ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
    if ds_cnt == 0:
        ax.set_title("Input data")
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright,
               edgecolors='k')
    # Plot the testing points
    ax.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright, alpha=0.6,
               edgecolors='k')
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    i += 1

    # iterate over classifiers
    for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
        ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

        # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
        # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
        if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
            Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        else:
            Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]

        # Put the result into a color plot
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cm, alpha=.8)

        # Plot the training points
        ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright,
                   edgecolors='k')
        # Plot the testing points
        ax.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright,
                   edgecolors='k', alpha=0.6)

        ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
        ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
        ax.set_xticks(())
        ax.set_yticks(())
        if ds_cnt == 0:
            ax.set_title(name)
        ax.text(xx.max() - .3, yy.min() + .3, ('%.2f' % score).lstrip('0'),
                size=15, horizontalalignment='right')
        i += 1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I also get the image1. 
[image: image1]

But I expect something like image2:
[image: image2]